# Calibre cuts full anime pages

Tags: calibre, pdf

I have a quick question about calibre.
My process is that is have a folder with JPG's of a manga that I read, I then zip that folder into a zip file and run it through calibre to get a PDF file in the end.
But I realized that calibre cuts out full pages and turns them into 2 separate pages.
Does anyone know what to tweak in calibre to keep those full pages ?

Cheers!